# Form is instantiating multiple times in custom event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having an issue that I'm sure there's a simple fix to but I'm new to WinForms. I'm building an application that needs to be able to instantiate a fully functional input form from the main form and a list view form when a list view item is double clicked. Instantiating from the main form works perfectly but, when I try to instantiate from the list view form, I get multiple instances of the form. It's as if the previous instance is being added to a list somewhere and, however many times I've double clicked in the list view, that's how many new input windows open.

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that I'm daisy-chaining a custom event handler from the list view form to the main form and then from the main form to the input form.

Here's the custom event handler that passes the list view form to the main form:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenuForm mainMenuForm = Application.OpenForms[0] as MainMenuForm;

    selectedCharacter = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag as Character;

    CharDoubleClick += mainMenuForm.HandleCharDoubleClick;

    if(CharDoubleClick != null)
    {
        CharDoubleClick(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Here, the selected character from the list view form is extracted and passed to the input form to populate its fields:

```
public void HandleCharDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CharListForm extractForm = new CharListForm();
    extractForm = sender as CharListForm;

    selectedCharacter = extractForm.SelectedCharacter;

    CharCreatorForm characterCreator = new CharCreatorForm();

    CharDoubleClick += characterCreator.HandleCharDoubleClick;
    characterCreator.CharCreatorFormClosed += HandleCharCreatorFormClosed;

    if (CharDoubleClick != null)
    {
        CharDoubleClick(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    characterCreator.Show();
}
```

And here, the selected character is extracted into the input form and the fields are populated:

```
public void HandleCharDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenuForm extractForm = sender as MainMenuForm;
    Character selectedCharacter = extractForm.SelectedCharacter;

    PopulateFields(selectedCharacter);
}
```

Everything is working as desired except for the fact that the second time the list view is double clicked, two input forms are instantiated, three appear on the third try, four on the forth, etc.

Comment: Check this line `CharDoubleClick += mainMenuForm.HandleCharDoubleClick;` You are adding an event handler with every double click. If you double click 5 times, 5 event handler would be added and `HandleCharDoubleClick` would be called 5 times.

Comment: One simple fix, other that doing it only at some init point, is to unhook before hooking..

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This was exactly the information I needed to get on the right track